# How to submit for different actions from two different button using Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have one basic JSP page having one text field and two buttons as shown below.

```
 <input id="tags" size="60" maxlength="60" autofocus name="config">
```

Two buttons one is for Action1 and other is for Action2.

```
<form action="action1" method="get">
<div class="ui-widget" align="center">
  <p>
    <label for="tags"><strong><br>
      <br>
    DUT Name</strong>: </label>
    <input id="tags1" size="60" maxlength="60" autofocus name="config1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="tags2" size="60" maxlength="60" autofocus name="config2">
  </p>
</div>
</form>
```

Every time i submit action1 is invoked,(As mention in form element) how can i invoke action2 when user press button2. Meaning how to invoke different actions when user press button1 and button2.

Assuming both actions can handle same text field and my Action Class and Struts.xml file have no issue.

Comment: you need two forms

Comment: I can add two forms, but how each action can get value from Same text field. As it will be only one text field, and two buttons, and as you mention two forms.

Comment: I just made an example implemented by Jquery.Hope it  can help you.

Comment: Not a dupe. OP wants to invoke different actions, not to detect submit button value in the same action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function submitForm(newActionValue){

 alert($("#testForm").attr('action'));
 
 $("#testForm").attr('action',newActionValue);
 
 alert($("#testForm").attr('action'));
 
 $("#testForm").submit();
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm" action="XXX" method="post">
 name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
 <br/>
 password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
</form>

<button id="button1" onclick="submitForm('action1')">button1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="submitForm('action2')">button2</button>
```

Comment: The action's value of the form will be changed when you click the buttons.So you can submit two different actions by using a form.

Comment: With S2 there is no need for js solution to do that.

Comment: You don't need `action="XXX"`

Comment: @AleksandrM How can i do that with out JS? Thanks.

Comment: @Ammad you can, though not recommended, use dynamic method invocation.

Comment: @Will DMI is turned off as well as action prefix due to security vulnerabilities of the previous releases. And these releases were not outdated. If you enable some features on your own risk you should be responsive to what are you doing.

Comment: You could return a value with the submit button and based on the value returned run a different event on the Java side if you want to avoid JS and the issue above (if no value returned just ignore the request).